# Why won't my iron golem farm work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

it seems like everything is in order, tons of villagers, and tons of doors, but nothing is working!I have 40 doors, and idk even how many villagers. here are some pictures.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the farm to work, you need to block the sky light from reaching the area at maximum intensity (15) for it to be recognized as a "house". **Just place a roof made of opaque blocks above the farm.**

Comment: This "roof" can actually count as a secondary spawning platform for golems. Repeat the same setup on the second level to increase the efficiency of the farm!